# Finding a drop in requests per second with Prometheus

Tags: promql

I keep count of my logs per second with a counter metric like this:

```
my_logs_count
```

I keep track of my logs per second by using a sum/rate like this:

```
sum(rate(my_logs_count[5m]))
```

I want to calculate a 30 percent drop in my rate per second.  The usual way to get a percentage drop would be something like this:

```
((sum(rate(my_logs_count[5m])) - sum(rate(my_logs_count[5m])) offset 5m) / sum(rate(my_logs_count[5m])) offset 5m) < -.3
```

Is there a better way to calculate a 30 percent drop?

Answer (score 0):

If you need drop in relative points your query is correct.

If you don't need value of drop you could simplify your expression to

```
sum(rate(my_logs_count[5m])) < 0.7 * sum(rate(my_logs_count[5m])) offset 5m
```

But based on your description I doubt that you really need `rate` here. It seems like you are looking for changes in `increase`.

Query

```
sum(increase(my_logs_count[5m])) < 0.7 * sum(increase(my_logs_count[5m])) offset 5m
```

Will check that number of logs generated during last 5 minutes is less than 70% of logs generated for 5 minutes 5 minutes ago.
Or

```
(sum(increase(my_logs_count[5m])) - sum(increase(my_logs_count[5m])) offset 5m) / sum(increase(my_logs_count[5m])) offest 5m < -0.3
```

for relative value.